# WPF binding UserControl to MainWindow as parent is failed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am newbie in XAML Databinding and I am stuck in this situation. I am using Mahapps MetroWindow.

Suppose that I have a UserControl named usrctrl_Camera_Control. I have a simple button there. The C# code is given below.

```
namespace TA141501005
{
public partial class usrctrl_Camera_Control : UserControl
{      
    public usrctrl_Camera_Control()
    {        
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The XAML is given below

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Custom="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TA141501005" x:Class="TA141501005.usrctrl_Camera_Control"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366" Background="#FF2B2B2B" Height="738" Width="1336">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>     
    <Button x:Name="btn_Test" Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsNyetEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
</Grid>
```

The C# code for MainWindow is given below.

```
namespace TA141501005
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>

public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    usrctrl_Camera_Control usrctrl_camera_control;
    public bool IsNyetEnabled { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        IsNyetEnabled = false;            
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();      
        usrctrl_camera_control = new usrctrl_Camera_Control();
    }
}
```

}

and the XAML code for MainWindow is given below.

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="TA141501005.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="Macromium System Control V1.0ES - TA141501005 [Engineering Sample]" Height="768" Width="1366" Background="#FF2B2B2B" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" IsMinButtonEnabled="False" IsWindowDraggable="False" ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" ShowMinButton="False" ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="False" IconOverlayBehavior="Flyouts">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btn_test" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="589,590,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNyetEnabled}"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to binding the property IsEnabled in btn_test in usrctrl_Camera_Control and btn_test in MainWindow into IsNyetEnabled in MainWindow. I set the IsNyetEnabled into false before I do InitializeComponent() in MainWindow.

The binding between btn_test.IsEnabled in MainWindow into IsNyetEnabled in MainWindow is done flawlessly. The btn_test in MainWindow is no longer enabled. (I know, I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the subsriber if there is any change but for now, just leave it as is for simplicity).

But, the binding between btn_test.IsEnabled in usrctrl_Camera_Control into IsNyetEnabled in MainWindow is failed. I have used Visual Studio "Create Data Binding" wizard but it always return error when compiling.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='TA141501005.MainWindow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsNyetEnabled; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='btn_Test'); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
```

Do you have any suggestion? I have tried for whole day without a luck.
Is there any way to access parent datacontext without removing this.Datacontext = this?
Looking forward for your suggestion and explanation.
Thank you very much.

Edit.
I display my UserControl via Flyout.

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
object obj = parentWindow.FindName("mainFlyout");
Flyout flyout = (Flyout) obj;  
flyout.Content = new SomeFlyOutUserControl();
flyout.IsOpen = !flyout.IsOpen;
```

Comment: Are you using a `Frame` to display the `UserControl` in the `MainWindow`? Please add that piece of code in the question.

Comment: @AnandMurali I am using flyout to display my UserControl.

    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    object obj = parentWindow.FindName("mainFlyout");
    Flyout flyout = (Flyout) obj;  
    flyout.Content = new SomeFlyOutUserControl();
    flyout.IsOpen = !flyout.IsOpen;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `IsNyetEnabled` property as a dependency property on the `MainForm`. This is the [mechanism that will propagate changes in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNyetEnabledProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsNyetEnabled", typeof(bool), 
    typeof(MainWindow),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool IsNyetEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MainWindow.IsNyetEnabled); }
    set { SetValue(MainWindow.IsNyetEnabled, value); }
}
```

To that you can bind your `Button` in the `MainWindow` directly.

For the UserControl though we have to add a shim, because the `UserControl` won't be able to find the ancestor when you create it.
Create on your `UserControl` like Moez posted another `DependencyProperty`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsButtonEnabledProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsButtonEnabled", typeof(bool), 
    typeof(usrctrl_Camera_Control),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

public bool IsButtonEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(usrctrl_Camera_Control.IsButtonEnabledProperty); }
    set { SetValue(usrctrl_Camera_Control.IsButtonEnabledProperty, value); }
}
```

Bind your `UserControl` button `IsEnabled` property to that.

Now as a last step we will have to connect the two Dependency Properties when you create your `UserControl`.

```
<local:usrctrl_Camera_Control x:Name="yourControl" ...Whatever else... IsButtonEnabled="{Binding Path=IsNyetEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}} />
```

This should work now.

Comment: It still gives me invalid binding.

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='TA141501005.MainWindow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsNyetEnabled; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name='btn_Test'); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')

Do I have to set DataContext for MainWindow and DataContext for the UserControl manually?

Comment: Is this binding error possibly coming form the Button Binding on your main window and not from your user control? You called them both the same name hence maybe the confusion. Use the same binding expression on that main window button: `IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsNyetEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}` and let me know if that works

Comment: Regarding `DataContext`: No the `RelativeSource` part where it will traverse the tree to find the right ancestor and therefore context should take care of that part.

Comment: I am afraid not. I have renamed the button so that they have different name and I cannot get the binding working. I am still receiving the same binding error.

Comment: So I'm guessing what happens is that when the binding is created/evaluated your `UserControl` that has the button on it is not in the tree as a child of your `MainWindow` yet, hence looking up the ancestor will not work. A very unelegant solution would be to create another `DependencyProperty` on your `UserControl` and bind the button to that. Then you go and bind the `UserControl` Dependency Property to the `MainWindow` `DependencyProperty`. But that is the best I can come up with right now. I'll reflect my answer in a few minutes with that solution.

Comment: Guess what... It works!
I modify your idea a bit. The last step, instead of using XAML, I use C# because I do not create that UserControl in XAML. I create the UserControl during runtime. So it would be like this.
usrctrl_camera_control = new usrctrl_Camera_Control();
Binding b = new Binding("IsNyetEnabled");
            b.Source = this;
            b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            usrctrl_camera_control.SetBinding(usrctrl_Camera_Control.IsButtonEnabledProperty, b);

Yes... whenever IsNyetEnabled is false in MainWindow, the appropriate button in usrctrl_camera_control is disabled. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `DependencyProperty` :

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty IsButtonEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsButtonEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool IsButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsButtonEnabledProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsButtonEnabledProperty, value); }
        }
```

// Here Rename your UserControl To *Test*

```
 <Grid>     
        <Button x:Name="btn_Test" Content="Button" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsButtonEnabled, ElementName=Test}"}" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Didn't @Bagus want to access the property of the MainWindow inside the UserControl? So the DependencyProperty should reside in the MainWindow...

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yes, I want to access the property of the MainWindow inside the user control (i.e. binding button.IsEnabled in usercontrol to bool property in MainWindow.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank J suggested, I modify his last step.
I create the usercontrol during runtime, not from the XAML. Therefore it would be look like this for the last step.

```
 usrctrl_camera_control = new usrctrl_Camera_Control();
 Binding b = new Binding("IsNyetEnabled");
 b.Source = this;
 b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
 usrctrl_camera_control.SetBinding(usrctrl_Camera_Control.IsButtonEnabledProperty, b);
```

Thanks all.. I hope it would be useful for those who have the same problem with me.